# Sending remember me checkbox in dataString

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

I'm trying to find out if a checkbox in a form is checked and if it is then append a value to a string called dataString.

Is the following code appropriate?

```
var remember = $('#remember').attr('checked'); 

if (remember == True) {
dataString += &remember=True;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do this.
Actually, wich server side language are you using?

Comment: You are using a server side language correct?

Comment: I'm sorry. The question is... Am I doing it correctly. I'm using jquery.

Comment: jQuery runs on the client, what code is running on the server to parse the data in the query string that your jQuery builds? C#? php?

Comment: php but i'm asking about the client side

Comment: So I have this now but it says prop is not a function.  var remember = $('#remember').prop('checked'); 
                        var dataString = 'username=' + username  + '&password=' + password + '&submit=True';
                        if (remember) {
                            dataString += '&remember=True';
                        }

Comment: In javascript it's `true`, not `True`. Additionally, strings must be quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer your question about adding to string, but as many of the comments have said, your question isn't clear as to whether you are asking about string operations or whether you are using that string properly in your submit/get/post/ajax call.

As of jQuery 1.6 you should be using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) (link to API documentation) to check properties.

```
var dataString = '';
var rememberIsChecked = $('#remember').prop('checked'); 

//if var is boolean, no need to test equality to true
if (rememberIsChecked) {
    dataString += '&remember=True'; //append to string
}
```

Comment: @Jeff Davidson, you should add your comments to the answers. Are you using a version of jQuery above 1.6?

Comment: Okay so I updated my links so that it is 1.6.1 and I did this to my code.  var remember = $('#remember').prop('checked'); alert(remember); if (remember) { dataString += '&remember=True'; } and it gave me an alert of undefined

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/2JCkn/2/ for an example

Comment: My fault i forgot to put id="remember" in the checkbox.

Comment: Are you using http://getfirebug.com/ to debug and see where the issue is? Does your `$('#remember')` selector return the checkbox?

Comment: Have you considered wrapping this in a form, making the login button a submit and letting the HTML take care of the posting for you?